# Shipping option not selected on review page when I selected shipping method in paypal express account in Magento2

Tags: magento2, paypal

> If I already selected shipping Method in Paypal express account and redirect to Magento2 review page then shipping option not selected by default on review page.

Comment: Have you fixed this point?I also need to re-select the shipping option in magento checkout page after redirection from paypal express.

Comment: I checked the code but no any solution found now.